# Steam not opening after half installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, steam, proprietary, amd-processor

Steam not opening after half installation on Ubuntu 14.04, i have installed the steam using command below

sudo apt-get install steam -y

it ran and completed and when i go to unity do a search for steam and click on it, nothing happens, it doesn't open at all, tried reinstalling through software center, synaptic package manager, downloaded the deb from steam website using dpkg, same results. checked out this forum for further solutions and shows many had the same problem and not a single quick fix, the best one suggest was install steam before installing the proprietary drivers for either AMD or Nvidia, but i have done the latter long back and for trying that out, i reloaded ubuntu 14 on Virtual box, first updated it with

sudo apt-get update, 
sudo apt-get upgrade
then sudo apt-get install steam -y

Steam was installed successfully and i configured it then i installed the AMD propitiatory driver which was needed for my processor AMD A4-4000, that too installed, did a reboot, but seems the driver was not installed and it remained in the same 640X480 resolution, more over once entering the password the screen freezes and it stays forever and i cant do a thing, please help.

i don’t want to try that in my PC and brick that too ....

Error when trying to open steam through Terminal

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
/home/vipinven1987/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  5474 Segmentation fault      $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/assert_20141231004040_1.dmp
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/vipinven1987/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/vipinven1987/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/vipinven1987/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20141231004043_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/vipinven1987/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730:  5599 Segmentation fault      $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have libcurl installed. Do so by installing `sudo apt-get install libcurl3`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

The following worked for me:

- removed the steam package again

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge steam
  ```
- removed the proprietary AMD driver (fglrx) in the software center
- installed the steam package again in terminal using

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i ./steam_latest.deb
  ```
- started steam again in the terminal with command `steam`
  the client started und upgraded itself
- installed again the proprietary AMD driver. I downloaded all 4 .deb packages from AMD site, installed them using

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Start all over again:

1. `sudo apt-get purge steam` to completely remove Steam and everything associated with it.
2. `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/steam.deb` to install Steam from the DEB package downloaded from steampowered.com
3. Start Steam from terminal to get any error messages: `steam`

**Do not use the `-y` switch** if you aren't for 100% sure what questions could be asked. I once did an `apt-get` command, which resulted in another question whether I wanted to continue, because it may harm my system. Gladly I didn't use `-y`.

Comment: Error #    
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/vipinven1987/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20141231004043_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/vipinven1987/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730:  5599 Segmentation fault      $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"

Comment: Just got the above error, couldn't paste the entire error due to size constraints :(

Comment: Please add the full error to your question as an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/566956/edit).

Comment: Just added please have a check